# How to serialize a Func<int, int> (or even a general delegate) type field with DataContract/DataMember in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I am trying to serialize a `Func<int, int>` field marked with `[DataMember]`, of a class marked with `[DataContract]`, whose target or Lambda expression definition is also part of the contract or could even be in the class itself.

I am using a custom `DataContractResolver` which works perfectly well when I unmark the `Func` field but when I mark it, it does not resolve a `System.DelegateSerializationHolder` type needed for the serialization. I tried to add this type to my custom `DataContractResolver` but I can't find it in the System namespace.

I could redefine it in the `[OnDeserialized]` method of each client class that uses this class but then I would need to do this every time I use this class, which of course I would like to avoid (client classes are also part of the `DataContract`).

This serialization is used for the time being for saving the state of the app to disk, so saving delegates (or even events which I am not interested in) makes logical sense as it is all part of the object graph.

So how can I serialize this `Func<int, int>` using WCF's `DataContract`?

Comment: If you serialize a delegate, do you also want to serialize the instance the delegate is attached to?

Comment: As I said, all the classes involved are part of the DataContract and are part of the serialization.

Comment: Yes... but "involved" does not mean "serialize" and a "class" is not the same as an "instance". That is why I asked clearification.

Comment: The Func field belongs to a class that is getting serialized. Its definition (usually a Lambda expression) is also in a class that belongs to the total object graph that gets serialized. The class that uses all these is also part of that same object graph. So it is basically a closed system that gets serialized maintaining all object references.

Comment: Is binary serialization an option for you?

Comment: Do you mean the use of the `Serializable` attribute with a binary serializer?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: It is too much work to implement in this project (which is quite big) and redefining the Func delegate each time on deserialization would be much easier (and it works). Plus WCF is a better choice in case we need to transmit objects across boundaries in the future.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that it's not possible to use the default WCF serializer for this - delegate serialization will only ever work for .NET.

The solution is to use `NetDataContractSerializer` instead. In your case, with a persistence context (or `File` context):

```
var context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.Persistence);
var s = new System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer();

var sb = new StringBuilder();

using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb)))
{      
    s.WriteObject(writer, new Test() { SomeFunc = (int i) => "Hi".Dump().Length });
}

sb.ToString().Dump();

[DataContract]
class Test
{
    [DataMember]
    public Func<int, int> SomeFunc;
}
```

Do note that the serializer will only maintain the *information* about the delegate - that's fine if you're only using compile-time methods for your delegates, but it will *not* work for dynamically compiled methods. Be warned.

It would also be a good idea to avoid anonymous functions - while they *will* work, they might also change between different builds, causing your persisted state to become invalid, possibly with disastrous side-effects. Don't forget, the delegate is serialized by method+class name (and return type, and arguments...) - when the name changes, the persisted delegate will point to the new method with the old name. Even with non-anonymous methods, try to make sure you never change the methods that might have been persisted as delegates - ideally, using the original method signature to provide backwards-compatible behaviour, if necessary.

If you ever find yourself adding support for network serialization, just add more `StreamingContextStates`.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically compiled methods". In my case I don't know the actual `Func<int, int>` until runtime, when it is fetched by a method according to some runtime parameters.

Comment: @GDS That's fine. The problem would be if the method didn't exist in the compile-time code at all - for example, if it was a result of compiling an expression tree (e.g. `LambdaExpression`) in run-time. If you did have run-time generated code involved, you'd have to add an extra layer or two to handle it deterministically.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is a few years old.  I found a way to solve this, well more I used mikecodes.net knowledge.  So check out his site for more info.  Here is my simplification:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using System;

public static class Script
{
    public static Func<int, int> Compile(string code) => CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<Func<int, int>>(code, ScriptOptions.Default).Result;
}
[Serializable] // DataContract stuff
public class Data
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    private Func<int, int> _func = null;
    public Func<int,int> Function
    {
        get
        {
            if(_func ==null)
            {
                _func = Script.Compile(this.Code);
            }
            return _func;
        }
    }

}
public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        var data = new Data
        {
            Code = "i=>i + 1",
            Name = "Sample",
            Value = 2
        };
        Console.WriteLine($"Function = {data.Function(data.Value)}");
    }
}
```